# Create-React-App requires Node 4.0 or higher

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I installed NodeJs LTS v6.9.5 for windows, and then did 
npm -g install create-react-app
But it gave me a warning that I need node 4.0

When I run node --version, I got 0.12.2

And when I run :
create-react-app hello-world 
I got the error:

"You are running Node 0.12.2
Create React App requires Node 4 or higher"

any idea how to make it work.

And why node version shows 0.12.2, when I installed NodeJs LTS v6.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple versions of node installed on your machine thats why it is showing `0.12.2`. Use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to change or switch node versions. (They are not supported on windows yet).

Comment: Thanks
I just found out that. It is not my machine, so it was installed before.